# Add new OU to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using this syntax for adding new `OU` to Active Directory:

```
var OUname = "VIP"

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyIp/OU=NEW,OU=MyUsers,DC=MyServer,DC=com");
de.Username = "administrator";
de.Password = "mypassword";
de = de.Children.Add("OU=NameNewOU", "OrganizationalUnit");
de.CommitChanges();
```

Everything work fine, but my question is how can I set variable instead of `OU=NameNewOU`?

Comment: Huh? Are you asking how to concatenate strings or what?

Comment: i would like to set OUname var instead of "OU=something"

Comment: And is there anything preventing you from doing it? Just do it and come back with a *specific* problem, if any.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you write this code your self? If so then you should not have problem with very simple and basic problem like this. If you are learning c# then learn basics first. You just have to use the variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything you need. I suggest you wrap your code with `using` statement, to prevent any memory leaks.

```
var ouName = "OU=" + "VIP"; //VIP will be the name of OU.

using(DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyIp/OU=NEW,OU=MyUsers,DC=MyServer,DC=com"))
{
   de.Username = "administrator";
   de.Password = "mypassword";

   de = de.Children.Add(ouName, "OrganizationalUnit");
   de.CommitChanges();
}
```

In this example, the `OU` will be created with `VIP` name.